How to Handle '429 Too Many Requests' Error in OpenAI API When Using React?
I'm building a React app that integrates with the OpenAI API for generating tags. However, I'm encountering a 429 Too Many Requests error frequently. How can I handle this error effectively? What are the best practices for managing API rate limits in a frontend application? Additionally, are there any security concerns when using environment variables for my API key in a React app? Any advice on debugging strategies and alternatives for mitigating these errors would also be appreciated.
const generateTags = async (text) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setIsOpen(true);

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${import.meta.env.VITE_OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages: [
          {
            role: "user",
            content: `Generate a list of relevant, SEO-friendly tags from this YouTube video title: "${text}". Make all letters lowercase and separate the tags with commas.`,
          },
        ],
        temperature: 0.5,
        max_tokens: 60,
        frequency_penalty: 0.8,
      }),
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        import.meta.env.VITE_OPENAI_API_URL,
        options
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error: ${response.statusText}`);
      }

      const json = await response.json();

      // Check if response has valid choices
      if (json.choices && json.choices.length > 0) {
        const data = json.choices[0].text.trim();
        setTags(data);
      } else {
        throw new Error("No tags generated.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error generating tags:", error);
      setTags("Failed to generate tags. Please try again.");
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

I attempted to generate SEO-friendly tags using the OpenAI API in my React app, expecting a successful response with the generated tags. Instead, I received a 429 Too Many Requests error, indicating that the API rate limit was exceeded.

Re the 429: if those occur, catch them and apply delays. Or better: get info from the OpenAI Docs on their limits and apply those in your code, to hopefully prevent the 429s from happening. Re the API key: if you're gonna put the React app on a public host and it has the API key embedded, then chances are that someone will harvest your key. The only fix is to have the key in a Backend API which then does all the talking with OpenAI when the Frontend needs it.

Try disabling React Strict Mode, as it sends all requests twice. It makes AI-based apps to be more expensive during development.

If you received 429 (too many request) error status code, you can attempt to call the api again after some delay. I provide full code to handle this case.
const generateTags = async (text) => {
  setLoading(true);
  setIsOpen(true);

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${import.meta.env.VITE_OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [
        {
          role: "user",
          content: `Generate a list of relevant, SEO-friendly tags from this YouTube video title: "${text}". Make all letters lowercase and separate the tags with commas.`,
        },
      ],
      temperature: 0.5,
      max_tokens: 60,
      frequency_penalty: 0.8,
    }),
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(import.meta.env.VITE_OPENAI_API_URL, options);

    // Here, handle 429 status code to call the api after some delay
    if (response.status === 429) {
      const retryAfter = response.headers.get("Retry-After") || 1;
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, retryAfter * 1000));
      return generateTags(text); // Retry the request after waiting
    }

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Error: ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    const json = await response.json();
    if (json.choices && json.choices.length > 0) {
      const data = json.choices[0].text.trim();
      setTags(data);
    } else {
      throw new Error("No tags generated.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating tags:", error);
    setTags("Failed to generate tags. Please try again.");
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};


yes i tried this code but still got the same error : App.jsx:37
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions 429 (Too Many Requests).

Then I think you can increase the delay time range.
